# problems of gazebo's installing and starting

Tags: gazebo, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

some problems occur when I am installing and starting gazebo .I am appreciated to you if you can help me !It displays below:

```
**Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Exception [WindowManager.cc:103] Unable to create the rendering window
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
Unable to create the rendering window
Exception [WindowManager.cc:103] Unable to create the rendering window
[ INFO] [1362624187.585240917]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
gzserver: /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreTextureManager.cpp:42: static Ogre::TextureManager& Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton(): Assertion `ms_Singleton' failed.
Aborted**
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57354/problems-of-gazebo%27s-installing-and-starting/) by [Eric90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4370/eric90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably you are using a computer with nvidia graphics card (I got the same errors). Install [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and run your commands prefixed with 'optirun', eg. `optirun roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch`. It should work.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4370/eric90/) on 2013-03-07**:
thanks! I make it.